# sparc assembly and the %y register

Tags: assembly, sun, primes, division, sparc

I am currently working with a sparc computer and I am trying to know if a number is prime or not.

here is a part of the code :

```
        mov     0,%y            
        mov     3, %l1
        nop
        nop
        nop

        sdiv    %l1,2,%l3
        rd      %y, %l6         
        cmp     %l6, 0
```

So basicaly what we have here is 3/2. So there should be a reminder of 1. This reminder should be putted in the %Y register. But When I look at %Y, it is still at 0. Why is %Y still at 0 while it should show me a reminder of 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SPARC Architecture Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=5&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparc.org%2Fstandards%2FV8.pdf&ei=LxnASrL5DOWOjAfegKkb&usg=AFQjCNHBCCf9w6xej3cBsFf0E1Xabzy0Jg&sig2=89IpHMnj6_mSbBOigomPfQ), page 116, it's an implementation option whether or not to set %y in sdiv. Apparently, it's also an implementation option whether to implement it in hardware or software, so it seems that some software implementations don't set %y.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to SPARC V8 Manual page 115, for sdiv instruction, CPU will discard remainder.